# UML Sequence Diagram DSL like this one but in C#?

Tags: c#

Found this opensource in java
http://www.zanthan.com/itymbi/archives/cat_sequence.html
Anything like this in C# or VB.net ?

Comment: The link target tells nothing about "sequence". Care to spend the extra 1.5 minutes and elaborate on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what that link means. But are you looking for this? 
http://www.codeplex.com/sequenceviz/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ReflectorPlugin

Comment: Hi that's great, thank you !

If you know something that also works with source code and that is free let me also know ;)